# Check for string in "response.content" raising "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-requests

I am trying to see if a sentence is present in the response back from a request.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.eventbrite.co.uk/o/piers-test-16613670281')
text = 'Sorry, there are no upcoming events'

if text in r.content: 
   print('No Upcoming Events')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am not quite sure why this occurring and what the solution would be.

Comment: `content` attribute returns a binary representation of the response you need to use `text` attribute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`r.content` is a `bytes` object but `text` is `str`, so you can't do the `__contains__` (`in`) check on another directly.

You can easily (re-)define the `text` object to be a bytestring:

```
text = b'Sorry, there are no upcoming events'
```

Now, you can do `if text in r.content:`.

or you can use `r.text` to get the `str` representation directly, and use `text` as-is (as `str`).

Answer (score 11):

[`r.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) returns a `bytes` like object in Python 3.x. To check, do:

```
>>> type(r.content)
<class 'bytes'>
```

There are multiple ways to fix your issue. For example:

1. **Decode `r.content` to string**: You can `decode` it to string as:

   ```
   >>> text in r.content.decode()
   False
   ```
2. **Convert `r.content`  to `utf-8` string** as:

   ```
   >>> text in str(r.content, 'utf-8')
   False
   ```
3. **Define your `text`** to search **as a byte-string**. For example:

   ```
   text = b'Sorry, there are no upcoming events'
   #      ^  note the `b` here
   ```

   Now you may simply use it with `r.content` as:

   ```
   >>> text in r.content
   False
   ```
4. **Use [`r.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content)** instead of `r.content` to search for the string, which as the [document](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) suggests:

   > The text encoding guessed by Requests is used when you access `r.text`.

   Hence you may just do:

   ```
   >>> text in r.text
   False
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
if text in r.text:
```

[`r.text`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content) is the textual content that is returned. [`r.content`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) is the binary content that is returned.

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately due to how the site works the r.text returns no data. This info is very useful and will keep this in mind in future! :)

Comment: @PiersThomas then you need to check again. Your url returns the same content as string with `r.text`

Answer (score 4):

Requests returns a bytes object, you need to convert it to a string before performing the in

Here's a reference about built in types, one of which is bytes https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

the line of code you're looking for is something like,

```
if text in r.content.decode():
  print('No upcoming events')
```

by default decode assumes utf-8, you can pass in a different encoding if you need to though.